# VBA: Fill cells based on 'random' content from column

Tags: vba, excel, macros

i'll try to explain my problem.
I need to fill values based on one of four values that apears in cells (column).
I have a code

```
  Sub testmacro()


    If Sheets("List1").Range("A1") = "Keyword1" Then
Sheets("List1").Range("b1") = "60"
Sheets("List1").Range("c1") = "630"
Sheets("List1").Range("d1") = "0.7"
Sheets("List1").Range("e1") = "0.7"
        ElseIf Sheets("List1").Range("A1") = "Keyword2" Then
Sheets("List1").Range("b1") = "1500"
Sheets("List1").Range("c1") = "15750"
Sheets("List1").Range("d1") = "1.46"
Sheets("List1").Range("e1") = "1"
        ElseIf Sheets("List1").Range("A1") = "Keyword3" Then
Sheets("List1").Range("b1") = "1500"
Sheets("List1").Range("c1") = "15750"
Sheets("List1").Range("d1") = "2.98"
Sheets("List1").Range("e1") = "1"
        ElseIf Sheets("List1").Range("A1") = "Keyword4" Then
Sheets("List1").Range("b1") = "1500"
Sheets("List1").Range("c1") = "15750"
Sheets("List1").Range("d1") = "2.38"
Sheets("List1").Range("e1") = "1"    
    End If

    If Sheets("List1").Range("A2") = "Keyword1" Then
Sheets("List1").Range("b2") = "60"
Sheets("List1").Range("c2") = "630"
Sheets("List1").Range("d2") = "0.7"
Sheets("List1").Range("e2") = "0.7"
        ElseIf Sheets("List1").Range("A2") = "Keyword2" Then
Sheets("List1").Range("b2") = "1500"
Sheets("List1").Range("c2") = "15750"
Sheets("List1").Range("d2") = "1.46"
Sheets("List1").Range("e2") = "1"
        ElseIf Sheets("List1").Range("A2") = "Keyword3" Then
Sheets("List1").Range("b2") = "1500"
Sheets("List1").Range("c2") = "15750"
Sheets("List1").Range("d2") = "2.98"
Sheets("List1").Range("e2") = "1"
        ElseIf Sheets("List1").Range("A2") = "Keyword4" Then
Sheets("List1").Range("b2") = "1500"
Sheets("List1").Range("c2") = "15750"
Sheets("List1").Range("d2") = "2.38"
Sheets("List1").Range("e2") = "1"    
    End If
```

.
.
.etc
.
.
.
As you can see with this code only 2 rows will work but what if I needed 10000 rows? There is no way writing it like this. I need something that would go throught the column A, watch for Keywords and then fill the rest of row with correct values.
Thanks for the help!
(yea, Iam pretty new to VBA)

Comment: Have you tried [looping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for clue. I haven't tried much yet. Iam new to VBA, dont know what to look for so any tip is really welcomed.

Comment: Okay well make sure you try a few things and show us what hasn't worked, so we can help you understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify things by using a `With` statement to organize things. Also add `Select Case` statements to clean up the `If - Elseif - End If` notation. Then add `For` loops to make things easier to type. When looping, note that you can loop over columns and rows by using the `.Cells` notatation rather than `.Range` (For example `Sheets(1).Range("B5")` is the same as `Sheets(1).Cells(5, 2)`

For example:

```
For row = 1 to 2
    With Sheets("List1")
        Select Case .Cells(row,1)
            Case "Keyword1"
                .Cells(row,2)  = "60"
                .Cells(row,3)  = "630"
                .Cells(row,4)  = "0.7"
                .Cells(row,5)  = "0.7"
            Case "Keyword2"
                .Cells(row,2) = "1500"
                .Cells(row,3) = "15750"
                .Cells(row,4) = "1.46"
                .Cells(row,5) = "1"
            Case "Keyword3"
                .Cells(row,2) = "1500"
                .Cells(row,3) = "15750"
                .Cells(row,4) = "2.98"
                .Cells(row,5) = "1"
            Case "Keyword4"
                .Cells(row,2) = "1500"
                .Cells(row,3) = "15750"
                .Cells(row,4) = "2.38"
                .Cells(row,5) = "1"     
        end select
    end with
next col
```

To do this for any number of row just change the `For` line to something like this:

```
For row = 1 to 10000 ' if you know the exact amount or...

numRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Columns(1))
For row = 1 to numRows
     'do the rest
```

Comment: Also with your code the user manually has to input `lastrow` numbers. A `Do While` or `Do Until` loop is much more effective and requires less input from the user.

Answer (score 2):

This code should do exactly what you are looking for. Please change Keywords at the top to suit your requirements.

```
Sub GenerateRandomContent()
Dim Keywords(1 To 4) As Variant
Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = 1

'**************************************************
'*************** EDIT KEYWORDS HERE ***************
'**************************************************

            Keywords(1) = "Keyword1"
            Keywords(2) = "Keyword2"
            Keywords(3) = "Keyword3"
            Keywords(4) = "Keyword4"

'**************************************************
'**************************************************
'**************************************************

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1")

        Do While .Cells(RowNo, 1) <> ""

            If .Cells(RowNo, 1) = Keywords(1) Then
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "60"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "630"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "0.7"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "0.7"
            ElseIf .Cells(RowNo, 1) = Keywords(2) Then
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "1.46"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            ElseIf .Cells(RowNo, 1) = Keywords(3) Then
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "2.98"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            ElseIf .Cells(RowNo, 1) = Keywords(4) Then
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "2.38"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            End If
            RowNo = RowNo + 1
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

You could also use `Case Select` instead of `If`

```
Sub GenerateRandomContent()
Dim Keywords(1 To 4) As Variant
Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = 1

'**************************************************
'*************** EDIT KEYWORDS HERE ***************
'**************************************************

            Keywords(1) = "Keyword1"
            Keywords(2) = "Keyword2"
            Keywords(3) = "Keyword3"
            Keywords(4) = "Keyword4"

'**************************************************
'**************************************************
'**************************************************

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1")

        Do While .Cells(RowNo, 1) <> ""

            Select Case .Cells(RowNo, 1)
            Case Keywords(1)
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "60"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "630"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "0.7"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "0.7"
            Case Keywords(2)
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "1.46"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            Case Keywords(3)
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "2.98"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            Case Keywords(4)
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "2.38"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            End Select

            RowNo = RowNo + 1

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Or even simpler again

```
Sub GenerateRandomContent()
Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1")

        Do While .Cells(RowNo, 1) <> ""

            Select Case .Cells(RowNo, 1)
            Case "Keyword1"
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "60"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "630"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "0.7"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "0.7"
            Case "Keyword2"
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "1.46"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            Case "Keyword3"
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "2.98"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            Case "Keyword4"
                .Cells(RowNo, 2) = "1500"
                .Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15750"
                .Cells(RowNo, 4) = "2.38"
                .Cells(RowNo, 5) = "1"
            End Select

            RowNo = RowNo + 1

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There would not really be a need to define an array of keywords in this case, just to simplify the code. But it works too.

Comment: @TeePee its really just so the user can modify the code... as they seem to be beginning with VBA, giving the extra flexibility can sometimes help.